# Error inserting/deleting records ASP.NET web application deployed on Windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb, windows-server-2012-r2

I developed an ASP.NET web application and it worked fine locally with IIS express.

I created deployment package and installed the application on my Windows 2012 server.

When developing the application, I was using an mdf file with localdb v11.0. On the server, however, I wanted to use sqlserver express. I changed the connection string to

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\nameoffile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

After making this change I was able to connect to the application from another host on the network. Viewing data and using filters/search (built into stored procedures) works fine.

The error occurs when I try to insert new records or delete records. The message is:

> Server Error in '/Nameofapplication' Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details. )

I've turned off the firewall, allowed remote connections, started sql server browser and agent and various other solutions that I've found from googling without any luck.

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Comment: The connection string of Sql Server takes different arguments. Take a look here. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: If this issue is with the connection string, would it still be able to read the data? The only time the error happens with when making changes such as inserts or deletes.

Comment: No it should not be able to read data, or have any access to the database. The error message is pretty clear and your connection string is not valid.  Maybe you have the connection string more than one time inside your project?

Comment: But I am able to read data. The error only happens when I try to insert or delete.

Comment: Do the insert/delete functions use a different connection string?

Comment: No, they all use the same connection string.